# Boston Brawler - Sailor

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I'm trying to defeat the sailor for the Boston Brawler series of missions and it's straight up impossible. I can't even touch him. You fight on a ship and after disposing of his lackies your are left with him and he is impossible to hit. Every punch he blocks and if I block him, he blocks my counter.

I've seen on the internet the suggestion of using smoke bombs, but I can't. Apparently you can't access your weapons in the fight. I've also seen a suggestion about if you block him near a chair or table he will be damaged, but there is nothing on the ship like that and he won't follow you off the ship!

So what are you actually supposed to do here?!?

Playing on PC, console versions might have been different (I'm assuming the other suggestions work on console).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I did not find the Sailor as that much of a difficult target. In fact, i would argue that the sailor is the easiest of the bunch. There is a specific method to beating the sailor. I would admit though, that if you do not follow the specific steps it can be near impossible to defeat the sailor.

To defeat the sailor, simply do the following:

- **When the sailor throws a punch, simply counter the attack FIRST, then in the most fluid and natural manner possible use "Break Defence". If executed properly, the sailor will stumble and take advantage of that moment to spam hits on him, you should be able to finish him off quickly.**
- When I say "fluid", I mean that when you **press the "Counter" button followed by the "Break Defence" button, do so naturally, not too slow, not too fast. Do not rush to execute the combination, yet do not take your own sweet time.**
- This may take a bit of practice getting used to but within the span of your health, you should be able to try the combination 4-5 times. This is more than sufficient in finishing him off.
- It should quickly become clear to you that the "Breaking his defence" part is the trickiest of the steps. However, **as long as you keep on trying, and of course, follow my steps, you will get it eventually.**

If however, you are more of a visual person, check out the following video. It took the player below a few tries but he eventually got it:

Comment: The counter / break defense combo works. I thought I'd tried it before, but I guess my timing was off. Knowing that to be the right combo, I tried it again and won first time. I actually only needed to do it once and he was defeated.

Comment: Technically I think the button is labeled Disarm when it's after you counter am attack... And it didn't actually lower his health past a certain point. But after I countered and "disarmed" him, I just punched him once normally while he's staggered, and won the fight.